# How do I mention a member who has just entered my server in an embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to know how to mention a member who has just arrived in some server and my bot sends to the welcome lounge and mentions the person who has just arrived.

Like:

Welcome {new member}! Blablablabla ...

````
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    let welcomeMsg = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
    
    let welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#e23922")
        .setDescription("*```\n \n      Nous te souhaitons la bienvenue.\n ```*\n\n:love_letter:  ↬ '    '   ́.    ̀   ́ '     ̂ ' ` ᙏᥙɾᥲᥲ ꙆꙆᥱᴿᴾ` !    '   ̀           .\n\n**Grâce à toi nous sommes à member.guild.memberCount membres !**\n```diff\n-              Chikin School            -\n```") 
        .setThumbnail("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1d/f4/ec/1df4ece417ea8174ac2a3c635cf871b3.gif")
        .setImage("https://i.gifer.com/g27a.gif");
    
    await client.channels.cache.get("737621052003450992").send({ embed: welcomeEmbed })
    },
````

In this code, where could I put it?

Like this !

[image: like this image]

````
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    let welcomeMsg = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
    
    let welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#e23922")
        .setDescription("*```\n \n      Nous te souhaitons la bienvenue.\n ```*\n\n:love_letter:  ↬ '    '   ́.    ̀   ́ '     ̂ ' ` ᙏᥙɾᥲᥲ ꙆꙆᥱᴿᴾ` !    '   ̀           .\n\n**Grâce à toi nous sommes à member.guild.memberCount membres !**\n```diff\n-              Chikin School            -\n```") 
        .setThumbnail("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1d/f4/ec/1df4ece417ea8174ac2a3c635cf871b3.gif")
        .setImage("https://i.gifer.com/g27a.gif");
    
    await client.channels.cache.get("737621052003450992").send(`Bienvenue, ${member.toString()}`, { embed: welcomeEmbed })
    },
````

**ReferenceError: user is not defined** = corriged thanks.

Comment: There is no `user` in the code you show us. That code cannot possibly have caused that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mention a member in an embed, or they won't get a notification. You can use the following to mention the user just above the embed:

````
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    let welcomeMsg = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
    
    let welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#e23922")
        .setDescription("Welcome " + member.toString() + "*```\n \n      Nous te souhaitons la bienvenue.\n ```*\n\n:love_letter:  ↬ '    '   ́.    ̀   ́ '     ̂ ' ` ᙏᥙɾᥲᥲ ꙆꙆᥱᴿᴾ` !    '   ̀           .\n\n**Grâce à toi nous sommes à member.guild.memberCount membres !**\n```diff\n-              Chikin School            -\n```") 
        .setThumbnail("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1d/f4/ec/1df4ece417ea8174ac2a3c635cf871b3.gif")
        .setImage("https://i.gifer.com/g27a.gif");
    
    await client.channels.cache.get("737621052003450992").send({ embed: welcomeEmbed })
    },
````

Comment: I know you can't mention but I want it to be in the form of a mention.

Comment: Like the bot show the name of the new member without the mention, juste her/his names. I don't speak a fluent english so... T-T

Comment: **ReferenceError: user is not defined**

Comment: Thanks you ! I... Wow ! I've searched so hard and your answer made me so stupid now... T-T

Comment: Np! Toujours heureux d'aider d'autres français 